# SQL Cursor not working with where not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

`Hi everybody,
My target is to update a field of a table (TABLE1) which has different values from its master table (TABLE2) with a SQL Procedure.
The select is working (giving about 20 results) but the cursor is not.

```
DECLARE 
@NUMBER INT,
@MATRICOLA INT,
@VAR VARCHAR(MAX)
@ID INT;

DECLARE CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT  
TABLE1.ID
,TABLE2.[VAR]
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.NUMERO = TABLE2.NUMERO AND TABLE1.MATRICOLA = TABLE2.MATRICOLA
WHERE TABLE1.[VAR] <> TABLE2.[VAR]

OPEN CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR
INTO @ID, @VAR
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE1
SET [VAR] = @VAR
WHERE ID = @ID;

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR
INTO @ID, @VAR
END

CLOSE CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR;
```

After many tries, I think that the problem is in the part
WHERE TABLE1.[VAR] <> TABLE2.[VAR]
but i don't know how to substitute this with something else.
Thank you for your help.`

Comment: Why are you using a cursor *at all*? SQL is a set-based language. Cursors are rarely needed and result in the slowest possible execution. You can write an `UPDATE ... FROM ...` query to update one table with data from another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use cursors in the first place. SQL is a set-based language and cursors aren't just cumbersome, they're the slowest possible way of doing anything, as they force the query engine to work [by Row-By-Agonizing-Row](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/)  (that's an actual trade term), instead of using indexes, hashing and parallelism to match and filter rows in memory. Cursors are almost always the wrong solution to whatever problem you may have.

You can write an `UPDATE ... FROM...` query to update a table using the results of another query, eg:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [VAR] = Table2.VAR
FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table1 ON 
         TABLE1.NUMERO = TABLE2.NUMERO 
         AND TABLE1.MATRICOLA = TABLE2.MATRICOLA
WHERE TABLE1.[VAR] <> TABLE2.[VAR]
```

I replaced `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` because the clause `WHERE TABLE1.[VAR] <> TABLE2.[VAR]` eliminates NULL values. A NULL in SQL means the value is unknown. You can't compare one Unknown value with another for equality, as the only logical results is Unknown too. `TABLE1.[VAR] <> TABLE2.[VAR]` will be false even if both `Var` values are NULL.

If the `Numero` and `Matricola` columns are indexed, the database engine will use the indexes to find the matching rows and update them. If `Var` is also indexed it will use the index to find the rows that don't match. The actual type of matching will depend on the data statistics, eg using Hash matching or Nested loops.

You can inspect the execution plan of the query by clicking on `Display Estimated Execution Plan` in Management Studio, or hitting `Ctrl+L`. Azure Data Studio has an equivalent command.

Comment: Thank you very much. It obviously worked and you saved me a lot of time in other procedures too!